# How to Check CSV file headers for specific word in Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, if-statement, header, cell

I have several CSV files and their headers are similar for the first 10 columns and then they are different. So I need to check each of the CSV files and see if in the column 11 they have word ABC or XYZ or SOS so then I can apply my other function on each CSV depending on the header.
Can anyone please help me with the if conditions that I need to apply to read the headers and compare column 11 in header with the strings I mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use glob to loop for each csv, and pandas to read the columns names.

```
import glob

path = r"*.csv"  # The path to the folder containing your csv files

for file_name in glob.glob(path):  # Looping through the list of paths 
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name)

    list_of_column_names = list(df.columns)  # Getting the headers of your dataframe

    if 'ABC' in str(list_of_column_names[11]):
        print('ABC case')
    elif 'XYZ' in str(list_of_column_names[11]):
        print('XYZ case')
    elif 'SOS' in str(list_of_column_names[11]):
        print('SOS case')
    else:
        print('Other Case')
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java you have libraries to manage csv like [Super CSV](http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/examples_reading.html). And for Excel like [Jakarta Apache POI](http://www.kramirez.net/RI/Material/Librerias%20para%20PDF%20y%20DOC/POIindex.html). In Python I don't know if exists libraries like this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is now a verified answer which worked just fine for me.